# How can I fit my Website width to mobile devises' size with viewport?

Tags: android, iphone, safari

I have a web site which width is 1280px.
I want to fit the web site width to mobile devices size, when I see it first time.

Then, I use viewport meta tag as a following, but it won't work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280, initial-scale=0.25" />
```

How can I fit my Website width to mobile devices' size with viewport?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

The *width=device-width* should do the trick. The *initial-scale, maximum-scale and user-scalable* would prevent the user to apply any type of zoom to your website, you may remove it if this is not desired.